# Adding Scrollbar to Datatables Removes Its Responsiveness

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

My jQuery datatable gets pushed under my navheader and becomes invisible if there is too much content. I'd like to fix this and the only solution I found was to add a scrollbar using `scrollY: "200px"` and `scrollCollapse: true,` however this breaks the responsiveness of the datatable. Is there a way to either prevent the datatable from going under my navheader (stop adding rows at this point and start paginating) or have a scrollbar without breaking responsiveness? I tried adding `overflow-y: scroll` however no difference was made.

css:

```
.navheader a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navheader > * {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

#adminTable{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

table td{
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table td:nth-child(1){
    width:5%;
}

table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table th {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<%--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">--%>
<%--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">--%>
<%--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">--%>
<%--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mdb.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navheader">
        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
            <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </form>
            <div class="myDropdown">
                <button class="dropButton">${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdownContent">
                    <a href="${contextPath}/Account">Settings</a>
                    <a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="${contextPath}/">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </a>
        </c:if>
    </div>
<%--Profile: change password, image, ranking. View stats  --%>
<%--    --%>
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="adminModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="adminModalTitle">Details</h5>
                    <c:if test="${message != null}">
                        <p>${message}</p>
                    </c:if>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="modalForm"></form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="modalCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalSubmit" form="modalForm">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="adminContainer">
            <h3>Admin Panel</h3>
            <div class="adminMenuBar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="adminLink" data-value="user">Users</li>
                    <li class="adminLink" data-value="group">Groups</li>
                    <li class="adminLink" data-value="framework">Frameworks</li>
                    <li class="adminLink" data-value="focus">Foci</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="adminContent">
                <table id="adminTable" class="table dt-responsive" style="width: 100%">
                    <c:if test="${users != null}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
<%--                            <th></th>--%>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Roles</th>
                            <th>Groups</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                            <tr>
<%--                                <td></td>--%>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </c:if>
                </table>
                <input id="tableType" type="hidden" value="user">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<%--    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>--%>
<%--    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>--%>
<%--    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Admin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/FocusHTMLGen.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```